# Building a StructType from a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new spark and python and facing this difficulty of building a schema from a metadata file that can be applied to my data file.
Scenario: Metadata File for the Data file(csv format), contains the columns and their types: for example:

```
id,int,10,"","",id,"","",TRUE,"",0
created_at,timestamp,"","","",created_at,"","",FALSE,"",0
```

I have successfully converted this to a dataframe that looks like:

```
+--------------------+---------------+
|                name|           type|
+--------------------+---------------+
|                  id|  IntegerType()|
|          created_at|TimestampType()|
|          updated_at|   StringType()|
```

But when I try to convert this to a StructField format using this

```
fields = schemaLoansNew.map(lambda l:([StructField(l.name, l.type, 'true')]))
```

OR

```
schemaList = schemaLoansNew.map(lambda l: ("StructField(" + l.name + "," + l.type + ",true)")).collect()
```

And then later convert it to StructType, using

```
schemaFinal = StructType(schemaList)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.4.1/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 372, in __init__
assert all(isinstance(f, DataType) for f in fields), "fields should be a list of DataType"
AssertionError: fields should be a list of DataType
```

I am stuck on this due to my lack of knowledge on Data Frames, can you please advise, how to proceed on this. once I have schema ready I want to use createDataFrame to apply to my data File. This process has to be done for many tables so I do not want to hardcode the types rather use the metadata file to build the schema and then apply to the RDD.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Fields have argument have to be a list of `DataType` objects. This:

```
.map(lambda l:([StructField(l.name, l.type, 'true')]))
```

generates after `collect`  a `list` of `lists` of `tuples` (`Rows`) of `DataType` (`list[list[tuple[DataType]]]`) not to mention that `nullable` argument should be boolean not a string.

Your second attempt:

```
.map(lambda l: ("StructField(" + l.name + "," + l.type + ",true)")).
```

generates after `collect` a `list` of `str` objects.

Correct schema for the record you've shown should look more or less like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("created_at", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("updated_at", StringType(), True)
])
```

Although using distributed data structures for task like this is a serious overkill, not to mention inefficient, you can try to adjust your first solution as follows:

```
StructType([
    StructField(name, eval(type), True) for (name, type) in  df.rdd.collect()
])
```

but it is not particularly safe (`eval`). It could be easier to build a schema from JSON / dictionary. Assuming you have function which maps from type description to canonical type name:

```
def get_type_name(s: str) -> str:
    """
    >>> get_type_name("int")
    'integer'
    """
    _map = {
        'int': IntegerType().typeName(),
        'timestamp': TimestampType().typeName(),
        # ...
    } 
    return _map.get(s, StringType().typeName())
```

You can build dictionary of following shape:

```
schema_dict = {'fields': [
    {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'id', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'integer'},
    {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'created_at', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'timestamp'}
], 'type': 'struct'}
```

and feed it to `StructType.fromJson`:

```
StructType.fromJson(schema_dict)
```

Comment: I did not create a function, rather used df.replace to replace occurrences of int, string etc. I tried to use the first option eval - but it is still giving me the same error. Is there a way to convert data in my csv to dictionary format in pyspark?

Comment: You can try `Row.asDict` but you'll still need a mapping.

Comment: I have defined a mapping as   testDF = schemaLoans.replace(['int','string','timestamp'],['IntegerType()','StringType()','TimestampType()'],'type')  So this gives the final DF with the correct data types. can you please elaborate how do I use Row.asDict in this case? I want to automate the process of creating schema dictionaries for each of the metadata files I have because I have more than 100. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, for now I am just trying to apply the schema by using createDataFrame and I changed the data types to match the data, but now I am getting this error: TypeError: ... can not accept object in type <type 'unicode'>. Any help on this ?

Comment: Could you ask it as a separate question with a [mcve] and ping me with a link? My guess is you pass strings not Rows / tuples / ...

Comment: yes, i was passing it as a string and not a tuple, I corrected that and its working. Still not able to solve the DataType problem as whenever I include dAtatype, pyspark does not consider it as of DataType

Comment: Yes DataType objects

Comment: How much time I have wasted searching for this `schema_dict`! Thanks @zero323.

Answer (score 1):

Below steps can be followed to change the Datatype Objects

```
data_schema=[
    StructField("age", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True)
]



final_struct=StructType(fields=data_schema)

df=spark.read.json('/home/abcde/Python-and-Spark-for-Big-Data-master/Spark_DataFrames/people.json', schema=final_struct)



df.printSchema()

root
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
val columns: Array[String] = df1.columns
val reorderedColumnNames: Array[String] = df2.columns //or do the reordering you want
val result: DataFrame = dataFrame.select(reorderedColumnNames.head, reorderedColumnNames.tail: _*)
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?