# getting error name 'spark' is not defined

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

This is the code i used:

```
df = None

from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

for category in file_list_filtered:
    data_files = os.listdir('HMP_Dataset/'+category)

    for data_file in data_files:
        print(data_file)
        temp_df = spark.read.option('header', 'false').option('delimiter', ' ').csv('HMP_Dataset/'+category+'/'+data_file, schema = schema)
        temp_df = temp_df.withColumn('class', lit(category))
        temp_df = temp_df.withColumn('source', lit(data_file))

        if df is None:
            df = temp_df
        else:
            df = df.union(temp_df)
```

and i got this error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4296b4e97942> in <module>
      9     for data_file in data_files:
     10         print(data_file)
---> 11         temp_df = spark.read.option('header', 'false').option('delimiter', ' ').csv('HMP_Dataset/'+category+'/'+data_file, schema = schema)
     12         temp_df = temp_df.withColumn('class', lit(category))
     13         temp_df = temp_df.withColumn('source', lit(data_file))

NameError: name 'spark' is not defined
```

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize Spark Session then use `spark` in your loop.

```
df = None

from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('app_name').getOrCreate()

for category in file_list_filtered:
...
```

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-5737e4577c66> in <module>
     10     for data_file in data_files:
     11         print(data_file)
---> 12         temp_df = spark.read.option('header', 'false').option('delimiter', ' ').csv('HMP_Dataset/'+category+'/'+data_file, schema = schema)
     13         temp_df = temp_df.withColumn('class', lit(category))
     14         temp_df = temp_df.withColumn('source', lit(data_file))

NameError: name 'schema' is not defined

Comment: @ParamitaBhattacharjee, you are reading the csv file with `schema`, So need to define the schema https://stackoverflow.com/a/56504339 (or) you can remove `schema=schema` from `spark.read.csv`.

Comment: thanks actually i am using jupyter notebook so i am getting so many errors but if i do the same in google colab it works fine  thank you

Answer (score 1):

try defining `spark` var

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```