# Uploading custom schema from a csv file using pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, schema

I have a query about loading the schema onto cdsw using pyspark.
I have a dataframe which is created using a csv file

```
data_1 = spark.read.csv("demo.csv",sep = ",", header = True, inferSchema = True)
```

The data types are read wrong for most of the variable i.e around 60 of them,  I can't change them manually all the time. I know what the schema must look like.

Is there any way, I could load the schema as well from a csv file? Like it could read the dataset and override the schema which I am uploading.

Answer (score 1):

Read with custom schema so that u can define what exact datatype you wanted.

```
        schema = StructType([ \
            StructField("COl1",StringType(),True), \
            StructField("COL2",DecimalType(20,10),True), \
            StructField("COL3",DecimalType(20,10),True)
        ])

        df = spark.read.schema(schema).csv(file_path)
```

Comment: I have 100 variable, Cant specify them one by one. I have a csv file where I have a list of Attribute names and data types....How do I load this while reading a file

Comment: You will have to read the other csv and transform it into schema programmatically and pass that variable as schema.

Comment: Variable  data_type
V1 double
V2 String
V3 Double
V4 Integer..This is an example of my schema file. when I pass this info the get junk values. can you pls provide me the right approach to it?    code :/** reading Schema **/
sch_df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("schema.xlsx").schema

/**Passing schema **/
df = spark.read.schema(sch_df).option("header", "true").csv("sample.csv")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026070/building-a-structtype-from-a-dataframe-in-pyspark . Something similar to this you will have to implement. read the schema file and apply transformation then use that schema to read your original data.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the `schema.csv` and build an actual schema programmatically, then use it to load actual data.

**Notes**: The types in `schema.csv` must match with Spark [datatypes](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.types)

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# schema.csv
# variable,data_type
# V1,Double
# V2,String
# V3,Double
# V4,Integer

# data.csv
# V1,V2,V3,V4
# 1.2,a,3.4,5

dtypes = pd.read_csv('schema.csv').to_records(index=False).tolist()
fields = [T.StructField(dtype[0], globals()[f'{dtype[1]}Type']()) for dtype in dtypes]
schema = StructType(fields)

df = spark.read.csv('data.csv', header=True, schema=schema)

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- V1: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- V2: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- V3: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- V4: integer (nullable = true)

df.show()
# +---+---+---+---+
# | V1| V2| V3| V4|
# +---+---+---+---+
# |1.2|  a|3.4|  5|
# +---+---+---+---+
```