# How to pass structtype in a csv file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cdsw

I have around 300 variables and I am trying to pass customschema via csv.
Below is the sample code which I am using.
However on uploading the schema via csv files...The output doesnt contain columns list:

```
Output : StructType(List(StructField(StructType([,StringType,true)))
```

Code in CSV:

```
schema = StructType([ \
            StructField("COl1",StringType(),True), \
            StructField("COL2",DecimalType(20,10),True), \
            StructField("COL3",DecimalType(20,10),True)
        ])

# reading schema
sch_df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("schema.csv").schema
# Passing schema
df = spark.read.schema(sch_df).option("header", "true").csv("/sample.csv")
```

Can you please provide the right away to upload the schema via csv file?

Comment: How does the `schema.csv` look like? Could you post an example?

Comment: Does this look similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67196155/uploading-custom-schema-from-a-csv-file-using-pyspark/67579764#67579764?

Comment: The output doesn't contain what you want because you're using the wrong attribute. You want the method  `printSchema()`